# How to match elements of two arrays and return a value

Tags: python, arrays

I'm looking for help to improve my code. I have two arrays of different sizes and I'm assigning a value from one array to the index of another.
eg

```
a = np.array([[1,5],[2,8],[3,2],[4,6]])
b = np.array([[1],[1],[2],[4],[4],[2],[3],[2],[3]])
```

i'm mathching the items in the first columns then assigning the value from the second column of a to the corresponding row in b.

```
c = np.zeros([len(b),1])
for i in tqdm(range(len(b))):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if b[i,0]==a[j,0]:
            c[i] = a[j,1]
```

which returns

```
c = [[5],[5],[8],[6],[6],[8],[2],[8],[2]]
```

The problem is I have a very large data set and the for loop takes a really long time to run. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: [codereview.se] is for working code needing optimization.

Comment: sorry, I'm using python

Comment: Just added the `python` tag.

Comment: @TimBell What is `tqdm`?

Comment: @John1024 tqdm is just a progress bar that was in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `a` always of the format `[[1, ...], [2, ...], [3, ...], ...]`?

If it is, then you can save time by not iterating through `a` but instead just indexing into it. For example:

```
a = np.array([[1,5],[2,8],[3,2],[4,6]])
b = np.array([[1],[1],[2],[4],[4],[2],[3],[2],[3]])

c = np.array([[a[i[0] - 1][1]] for i in b])
# c = [[5], [5], [8], [6], [6], [8], [2], [8], [2]]
```

This will take order of size of `b` time instead of order of size of `a` times size of `b` time.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.